# micrometer statistics for RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I am trying to get metric for rest uri using `micrometer`. I read [this](http://micrometer.io/docs), [this](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/spring/1.5#_client_side_http_instrumentation), and also bunch of SO posts. After reading all these, I have a some questions about it.

1. For `micrometer` to work correctly uri should be parameterized([Reference](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/98#issuecomment-324100208)). I assume this is only path variable not request params. Am i correct?

   2. should we not use `UriComponentsBuilder` at all because we don't want to expand uri outside `resttemplate` and let `resttemplate` do it for us.
   3. lets say if i use this `restClient.getForObject( fooSvcUrl, FooBar.class, uriVariables );`, does `micrometer` looks at `fooSvcUrl` and it should be parametertized at this point ?
      I am asking this because if i do following, it will not work. AM I correct ? `restClient.getForObject(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(fooSvcUrl).buildAndExpand(uriVariables ).toUri() , FooBar.class);`

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to deal with all that stuff, so I can give you the following answers:

**1.** "Parametrized" means here that you apply placeholders into the URI, regardless of their position. Basically, you can parametrize everything in the URI - the scheme, the host, path variables and even query parameters, as long as you provide values to replace the placeholders.

As such, the following URIs will work when passed to `RestTemplate`:

```
https://www.foo.bar/baz/{id} with {"id":1}
https://www.foo.bar/baz?id={id} with {"id":1}
https://{host}/foo/{id}?target={target} with {"host":"www.foo.bar", "id":1, "target":"baz"}
```

**2.** You should not, especially if you would expect reserved symbols that would be put into your URI, as `UriComponentsBuilder` will try to encode them immediately which results in `RestTemplate` doing a double tap on the encoding, turning a non-fragment `#` first into a `%23` and then into a `%2523`.

**3.** You are right, the URI should be parametrized when used as an argument for `RestTemplate.getForObject`, as the overloaded methods taking parameter value arguments will expand it before actually performing the request.